# Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) with StringSubsequenceKernel

Tags: python, python-2.7, shogun

I'm long time trying to install the shogun library to use the StringSubsecuenceKernel. finally i did it for python 2.7.I use the code example from another answer from this site

```
from shogun.Features import *
from shogun.Kernel import *
from shogun.Classifier import *
from shogun.Evaluation import *
from modshogun import StringCharFeatures, RAWBYTE
from shogun.Kernel import StringSubsequenceKernel
import numpy
strings = ['cat', 'doom', 'car', 'boom']
test = ['bat', 'soon']
train_labels  = numpy.array([1, -1, 1, -1])
test_labels = numpy.array([1, -1])
features = StringCharFeatures(strings, RAWBYTE)
test_features = StringCharFeatures(test, RAWBYTE)
# 1 is n and 0.5 is lambda as described in Lodhi 2002
sk = StringSubsequenceKernel(features, features, 2, 0.5)
```

then when i try to do this

```
del sk
```

it gives me the following error

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

I'm using pycharm community edition 2017.2.4
and shogun library is installed in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/shogun` 
normally the installed packages  appears in the /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages directory, but this doesn't.
The question is , why i get this error and how can i avoid it?
thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also if i try to predict the new labels `svm.apply(test_features).get_labels()`  get the same error

Answer (score 0):

what's the version you are using of shogun?

Comment: i installed the libshogun16 version

Comment: Another interesting this that just happen is that i update my system an know i can't import the StringsubsecuenceKernel but the SubsecuenceStringKernel i can

Comment: first of all i would use libshogun17 or libshogun18. which is your OS/distro? maybe i can help you to figure out how you can get those easily

Comment: Sorry for the horrible orthography, i have just read what i write. I didn't install 18 or 17 because they didn't appear when i follow all the instructions on the Shogun site. just the 16. My OS/ distro is  ubuntu 16.04lts. thank you very much.

Comment: and you are using a ppa? if not please consider using:
https://launchpad.net/~shogun-toolbox/+archive/ubuntu/stable

Comment: Yeah i was using a PPA, but  it seems that the problem with the new module name isn't causing any truble , thank very much anyway :3